# How to create transparent semicircle on the CardView

Tags: android, view, android-cardview

The problem is that these semicircles should change position depending on the content.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0A1L.png

I have tried to do this using two CardView, but it was no what I want

Comment: you can make a drawable file of your background instead of cardview and achieve your functionality as you want !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a `drawable` png file by photoshop or any other image editing tool and use that in the background instead of cardview.

Hope it will help you to achieve your goal.

Thank you